# How to get all img tags from pagesource with anglesharp

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, anglesharp

i did use webview to get the full page source and i write it to a file

so now i need to extract all the images from the file

i read the file using StreamReader and i give it to the string Called TheHtmlSource as you see in the code

this is my code

```
        var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader();
        for (int i = 0; i < TheHtmlSource.Length; i++)
        {
            string theImageUrl = (await BrowsingContext.New(config).OpenAsync(TheHtmlSource))
                .DocumentElement.Descendents()
                .Where(x => x.NodeType == NodeType.Element)
                .OfType<IHtmlImageElement>()
                .Where(x => x.Attributes["class"]?.Value == "_icyx7")
                .Select(x => x.Attributes["src"]?.Value)
                .FirstOrDefault();
            int index = theImageUrl.IndexOf("?");
            string fixedImageUrl = theImageUrl.Remove(index);
            _list.Add(new AllImageUrls()
            {
                url = fixedImageUrl
            });
        }
```

but i doesn't work i keep getting NullReference Error

im using Xamarin In Visual Studio

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you post a tag from which you are trying to get img value?

Comment: .OfType<IHtmlImageElement>() img with calss="_icyx7" Selecting The Src

Comment: Did you post a whole tag? It's very important does it have spaces between or namespace

Comment: i'm using AngleSharp for extracting the specific tag with given attributes i didn't use the whole tag i just give the information of what i want to anglesharp as you can see in my code

Comment: Will this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36023919/get-and-download-pictures-with-anglesharp

Comment: i think that only returns the img tag and my page source does not end up with .jpg if see in my code             int index = theImageUrl.IndexOf("?");
            string fixedImageUrl = theImageUrl.Remove(index); im trying to remove rest of the link and i only want the url

Comment: Man you have to provide full informations. Believe me no one is going to guess what do you actually want. You are probably parsing the HTML What is your HTML source? Your title is how to get all img tags and suddenly you don't need img tags. Some confusing things are in your post. So make sure you update your question with full informations if you want to someone take look at your question.

Comment: the page source is exported by webview because source is rendering with javascript so i need to loaded with browser or something so i got the code and i write it to a file then i read it again and give that reading to string called TheHtmlSource as you can see in my code so in this case i got the source code man i just need to extract the images

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`await BrowsingContext.New(config).OpenAsync(addressString)` accepts a string, which should be an address. From your description, you are passing the source string to this method, which is not valid.

If you want to parse the source string, you can use `AngleSharp.Parser.Html.HtmlParser`, which you can find its usage by [AngleSharp  Documentation](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/wiki/Documentation).